# Check if point inside random boxes

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Edit: I've worked a solution.  Feel free to contact me if you come across this in the future and need something similar.

--

Instead of generating random points on a plane, how would you check if a given coordinate is equal to a random point?  Or inside a random bounding box?

For example you have a plane with integer coordinates.  That plane is somehow populated with random bounding boxes (generated using a formula, not data).  The goal is to check if a given (x, y) is within one of those boxes.

I can find many references on how to generate random points but not much for doing it in this more backwards way (I guess you'd call it 'functional'?).

I have managed to make an algorithm that splits the plane into 100x100 squares, and within each square is a bounding box that is randomly placed.  But is it possible with an algorithm that places the boxes more organically?

Edit: Here's an example algorithm I used for a simple "random point within a 100x100 grid" (from memory, might be missing something):

```
// check if equal to a random point within the point's grid square
boolean isRandomCenter(x, y) {
    // offset relative to origin of grid square
    int offsetX = x mod 100
    int offsetY = y mod 100

    // any random seed will do
    int randomSeed = x * y

    // random position of point for this square
    int randomOffsetX = random(50, randomSeed)
    int randomOffsetY = random(50, randomSeed)

    if (offsetX == randomOffsetX && offsetY == randomOFfsetY)
        return true

    return false
}
```

Comment: What do you want to know exactly ? What is the condition to know if a given point (x,y) is in a bouding box ? Or an algorithm to place boxes randomly ?

Comment: I guess they are both interlinked.  Just any kind of random distribution where you can have a function(x, y) that returns true if inside a bounding box for that distribution.  Preferably with other parameters that control the average spacing etc. but that doesn't matter too much.

Comment: "organically": is a term for which you have your own understanding, that we do not share. Same remark about "check if a given coordinate is equal to a random point". Please explain.

Comment: Aren't you after a method to place *non-overlapping* random rectangles ?

Comment: "Organic" as opposed to the grid style that I described.  Everything is integer-only, no reals.  I'd much prefer non-overlapping.

Comment: Presumably, organic means not grid style, while grid style must be non-organic ? Right ?

Comment: ""Organic" as opposed to the grid style"

Comment: Explaining the question better is much more likely to get you good answers than adding a bounty.

Comment: What part needs explaining?

Comment: `What part needs explaining?` What is the input? Where do random points/boxes come from? Are `boxes` quadrangles? Rectangular? Iso-oriented? What resource requirements are to be considered?

Comment: (It would seem that an online algorithm (allowing additions to the set of bounding boxes) would support generating a set without inclusions generate random points, reject if included in *set so far*, generate other vertices otherwise.)

Comment: It's an integer 2d number plane.  The goal is to accept x & y and spit out whether inside a box.  Boxes really need to be generated by the same function that is checking if inside.  Needs to apply to an infinite plane hence the requirement to check x, y rather than generate data for a certain area on the plane.

Comment: Minecraft's terrain generator is a real life example.  They don't generate the whole terrain before the player starts the game, because the world is infinite.  So they just generate terrain for the player's surrounding area as they explore.  Their function takes x & y and gives back true or false depending on whether you are inside a natural building, etc..

Comment: @LegendLength then what you call "organic" is referred to by most people as [fractal generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_landscape) or [procedural generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_generation).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if I exactly understand your problem, but the condition to know if a given point M(x, y) plotted in a 2 dimensional Euclidian space represented with two axes x and y is inside a box represented with two opposites points A(xa, ya) and B(xb, yb) is pretty simple.

Let's define a function isInsideTheBox(x, y, xa, ya, xb, yb) returning `true` if M is inside the box and `false` else :

```
bool isInsideTheBox(int x, int y, int xa, int ya, int xb, int yb) 
{
    // We assume xa < xb and ya < yb
    return (x >= xa && x <= xb && y >= ya && y <= yb); 
}
```

Comment: Yes I know how to check if you are within a box given a point.  My question is what sort of algorithms are available to produce an organic (non-grid based) set of random points and check if you are on that point (or within a box, easy modification).

Comment: @LegendLength You can understand our confusion, given that the title of your question is "Check if point inside random boxes"

Answer (score 1):

I am answering the question: check if a point is over a random point.

If the coordinates are real, the probability of an overlap is null and the question is virtually useless. So I assume discrete coordinates.

If the question regards random points that have already been drawn, the only way is to remember the random points in some container as you draw them (array, sorted, list, search tree, hash table).

If the question regards points that *might* be drawn at that location, the answer is "true" in the whole domain (where the distribution is nonzero). You need to model the domain geometrically to perform point-in-... queries.

---

If the question is about pseudo-random or quasi-random points, I don't think there is any shortcut and you should proceed as for the truly random case (unless the generator is really poor).

Comment: In my example algorithm, it both decides where the points are and also checks if you are on one of points.  It works for an infinitely large plane and doesn't store any data.  It can be easily modified to check for bounding box rather than landing on the exact point.  But it is limited to one per 100x100 grid square.  I want something more 'organic', as in you might have 5 points randomly next to each other which is impossible using the grid method.